# Show $ \varphi(x)=x \;\text {for all } x \in \mathbb{Q} \text {. } $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $ d \in \mathbb{N}$ be a number that is not a square, i. e. $ d \neq a^{2} $ for all $a \in \mathbb{N} $. We define
$
\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]:=\{a+b \sqrt{d} \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\} .
$
This is a subring of $ \mathbb{R} $ (no need to show that). Let $ R $ be another ring containing $ \mathbb{Q} $ as a subring. Let $ \varphi: \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}] \rightarrow R $ be a ring homorphism.

Show:
$
\varphi(x)=x \quad \text { for all } x \in \mathbb{Q} \text {. }
$

Attempt:
If $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, from $\varphi(1)=1$ it follows that $\varphi(n) = n$. Hence, if $q= a/b \in \mathbb{Q}$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers, we have
$$\varphi(q) = \varphi(ab^{-1}) = \varphi(a)\varphi(b)^{-1}= ab^{-1}= q$$

But how to argue further now?

Comment: You have the proof right? what else do you want to argue further?

Comment: You're already done. The fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ is initial in the category of rings with identity will come up repeatedly and noting $\varphi(0)=0$ and $\varphi(1)=1$ characterizes this property. Fields of characteristic zero will always have a copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ inside them for this reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but the problem statement is a massive red herring. In fact, in general, there is at most one ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Q} \to R$ for all rings $R$. We prove this by following your general logic.

In your situation, we have a ring $S = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ and a ring $R$. We have canonical inclusion homomorphisms $i_S : \mathbb{Q} \to S$ and $i_R : \mathbb{Q} \to R$. We are asked to show that $i_R = f \circ i_S$. Since both $i_R$ and $f \circ i_S$ are ring homomorphisms $\mathbb{Q} \to R$, they must be equal. The specific form of $S$ and the fact that $d$ is square-free are totally irrelevant.